# How to connect existing database file from vb. to my localhost

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have downloaded a `vb.net 2010` sample program from the internet, that program has database `DBUsers` and a table `tblUsers` on its Data Connection.

My question is: how to edit the inputs on these database? Because this database and table is *NOT* or "*not yet created*" on my **localhost**, how can I connect this database to my localhost so I can manually edit it from my browser?

The downloaded database back end is MySQL.
My database back end is MySQL too.

Comment: Can you show us the Db Connection String?

Comment: where i can find that?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="UserAccessLevel.My.MySettings.DBUsersConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBUsers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
    </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: is that it? i have found it on  App.config on the solution explorer

Comment: Going by that information its an MS Sql database not MySQL. Did you download the database files?